# Adding new XML elements using XSLT

Tags: xslt, element

I have the requirement in which I need to add the new elements. Can anyone please help where I am doing it wrong? I have attached the sample input, sample output and I have attached the code I am using as well :)

Sample Input:

```
<soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                <OrderCreate Version="5.1.1" xmlns="urn:midx:names:specification:ces:schema:all:5:1:1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                                <Header>
                                        <ThisDocumentIdentifier>
                                                <DocumentIdentifier>58585993</DocumentIdentifier>
                                        </ThisDocumentIdentifier>
                                        <ThisDocumentDateTime>
                                                <DateTime DateTimeQualifier="On">2014-08-22T00:00:00Z</DateTime>
                                        </ThisDocumentDateTime>
                                        <From>
                                                <PartnerInformation>
                                                        <PartnerName>MOSLLC</PartnerName>
                                                        <PartnerIdentifier Agency="IBM-EBID">0089646370000</PartnerIdentifier>
                                                        <ContactInformation>
                                                                <ContactName>MOSLLC </ContactName>
                                                                <ContactName>804-281-1402</ContactName>
                                                                <EmailAddress></EmailAddress>
                                                        </ContactInformation>
                                                </PartnerInformation>
                                        </From>
                                        <To>
                                                <PartnerInformation>
                                                        <PartnerName>Walmart</PartnerName>
                                                        <PartnerIdentifier Agency="IBM-EBID">0062668030000</PartnerIdentifier>
                                                </PartnerInformation>
                                        </To>
                                </Header>
                                <OrderCreateBody>
                                        <OrderCreateProperties>
                                                <PurchaseOrderNumber>
                                                        <DocumentIdentifier>OD3157538</DocumentIdentifier>
                                                </PurchaseOrderNumber>
                                                <PurchaseOrderTypeCode Domain="ANSI-ASC-X12-92">KN</PurchaseOrderTypeCode>
                                                <PurchaseOrderIssuedDate>
                                                        <DateTime DateTimeQualifier="On">2014-08-22T00:00:00Z</DateTime>
                                                </PurchaseOrderIssuedDate>
                                                <LanguageCode Domain="ISO-639-2T">eng</LanguageCode>
                                                <CurrencyCode Domain="ISO-4217">USD</CurrencyCode>
                                                <BuyerSequenceNumber>0</BuyerSequenceNumber>
                                                <DeliveryTerms>
                                                        <DeliveryTermsCode Domain="Incoterms-2000">CPT</DeliveryTermsCode>
                                                        <DeliveryTermsLocation>ORIGIN</DeliveryTermsLocation>
                                                </DeliveryTerms>
                                                <ShipmentMethodOfPaymentCode Domain="ANSI-ASC-X12-146">PC</ShipmentMethodOfPaymentCode>
                                                <PaymentTerms>
                                                        <PaymentTermsOfSale>
                                                                <TermsOfSaleDescription>DUE 25TH OF FOLLOWING MONTH</TermsOfSaleDescription>
                                                                <NetDaysDue>0</NetDaysDue>
                                                        </PaymentTermsOfSale>
                                                </PaymentTerms>
                                        </OrderCreateProperties>
                                        <OrderCreatePartners>
                                                <Buyer>
                                                        <PartnerInformation>
                                                                <PartnerName>MOSLLC</PartnerName>
                                                                <PartnerIdentifier Agency="IBM-EBID">0089646370000</PartnerIdentifier>
                                                                <ContactInformation>
                                                                        <ContactName>MOSLLC LLC</ContactName>
                                                                        <ContactNumber>804-281-1402</ContactNumber>
                                                                        <EmailAddress>Jim.Paul@sscoop.com</EmailAddress>
                                                                </ContactInformation>
                                                        </PartnerInformation>
                                                </Buyer>
                                                <Seller>
                                                        <PartnerInformation>
                                                                <PartnerName>WalmartPartnerName</PartnerName
                                                                <PartnerIdentifier Agency="IBM-EBID">0062668030000</PartnerIdentifier>
                                                        </PartnerInformation>
                                                </Seller>
                                                <ShipTo>
                                                        <PartnerInformation>
                                                                <PartnerName>ORANGE MADISON COOP ORANGE BR</PartnerName>
                                                                <PartnerIdentifier Agency="IBM-EBID">0238626420000</PartnerIdentifier>
                                                                <AddressInformation>
                                                                        <AddressLine>13323 JAMES MADISON HWY</AddressLine>
                                                                        <CityName>ORANGE</CityName>
                                                                        <StateOrProvince>VA</StateOrProvince>
                                                                        <PostalCode>22960</PostalCode>
                                                                        <PostalCountry>US</PostalCountry>
                                                                </AddressInformation>
                                                        </PartnerInformation>
                                                </ShipTo>
                                                <Payer>
                                                        <PartnerInformation>
                                                                <PartnerName>MOSLLC</PartnerName>
                                                                <PartnerIdentifier Agency="IBM-EBID">0089646370000</PartnerIdentifier>
                                                        </PartnerInformation>
                                                </Payer>
                                        </OrderCreatePartners>
                                        <OrderCreateDetails>
                                                <OrderCreateProductLineItem>
                                                        <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
                                                        <PurchaseOrderLineItemNumber>1</PurchaseOrderLineItemNumber>
                                                        <ProductIdentification>
                                                                <ProductIdentifier Agency="AssignedByManufacturer">883580921503</ProductIdentifier>
                                                                <ProductName>HARNESS XTRA 5.6L RUP BULK</ProductName>
                                                                <ProductDescription>HARNESS XTRA 5.6L RUP BULK</ProductDescription>
                                                        </ProductIdentification>
                                                        <ProductQuantity>
                                                                <Measurement>
                                                                        <MeasurementValue>1000</MeasurementValue>
                                                                        <UnitOfMeasureCode Domain="UN-Rec-20">GLL</UnitOfMeasureCode>
                                                                </Measurement>
                                                        </ProductQuantity>
                                                        <ScheduleDateTimeInformation ScheduleType="RequestedDelivery">
                                                                <DateTimeInformation>
                                                                        <DateTime DateTimeQualifier="On">2014-08-22T00:00:00Z</DateTime>
                                                                </DateTimeInformation>
                                                        </ScheduleDateTimeInformation>
                                                </OrderCreateProductLineItem>
                                        </OrderCreateDetails>
                                </OrderCreateBody>
                        </OrderCreate>
                </soapenv:Body>
```

Expected output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <OrderCreate Version="2.0.2">
                            <Header xmlns="urn:midx:names:specification:ces:schema:all:5:1:1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                                    <ThisDocumentIdentifier>
                                            <DocumentIdentifier>58585993</DocumentIdentifier>
                                    </ThisDocumentIdentifier>
                                    <ThisDocumentDateTime>
                                            <DateTime xmlns="" DateTimeQualifier="On">20140822000000</DateTime>
                                    </ThisDocumentDateTime>
                                    <From>
                                            <PartnerInformation>
                                                    <PartnerName>MOSLLC</PartnerName>
                                                    <PartnerIdentifier Agency="IBM-EBID">0089646370000</PartnerIdentifier>
                                                    <ContactInformation>
                                                            <ContactName>MOSLLC </ContactName>
                                                            <ContactName>804-281-1402</ContactName>
                                                            <EmailAddress/>
                                                    </ContactInformation>
                                            </PartnerInformation>
                                    </From>
                                    <To>
                                            <PartnerInformation>
                                                    <PartnerName>Walmart</PartnerName>
                                                    <PartnerIdentifier Agency="IBM-EBID">0062668030000</PartnerIdentifier>
                                            </PartnerInformation>
                                    </To>
                            </Header>
                            <OrderCreateBody xmlns="urn:midx:names:specification:ces:schema:all:5:1:1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                                    <OrderCreateProperties>
                                            <PurchaseOrderNumber>
                                                    <DocumentIdentifier>OD3157538</DocumentIdentifier>
                                            </PurchaseOrderNumber>
                                            <PurchaseOrderTypeCode Domain="ANSI ASC X12 92">KN</PurchaseOrderTypeCode>
                                            <PurchaseOrderIssuedDate>
                                                    <DateTime xmlns="" DateTimeQualifier="On">20140822000000</DateTime>
                                            </PurchaseOrderIssuedDate>
                                            <LanguageCode Domain="ISO 639-2/T">eng</LanguageCode>
                                            <CurrencyCode Domain="ISO 4217">USD</CurrencyCode>
                                            <BuyerSequenceNumber>0</BuyerSequenceNumber>
                                            <DeliveryTerms>
                                                    <DeliveryTermsCode Domain="Incoterms-2000">CPT</DeliveryTermsCode>
                                                    <DeliveryTermsLocation>ORIGIN</DeliveryTermsLocation>
                                            </DeliveryTerms>
                                            <ShipmentMethodOfPaymentCode Domain="ANSI-ASC-X12-146">PC</ShipmentMethodOfPaymentCode>
                                            <PaymentTerms>
                                                    <PaymentTermsOfSale>
                                                            <TermsOfSaleDescription>DUE 25TH OF FOLLOWING MONTH</TermsOfSaleDescription>
                                                            <NetDaysDue>0</NetDaysDue>
                                                    </PaymentTermsOfSale>
                                            </PaymentTerms>
                                    </OrderCreateProperties>
                                    <OrderCreatePartners>
                                            <Buyer>
                                                    <PartnerInformation>
                                                            <PartnerName>MOSLLC</PartnerName>
                                                            <PartnerIdentifier Agency="IBM-EBID">0089646370000</PartnerIdentifier>
                                                            <ContactInformation>
                                                                    <ContactName>MOSLLC LLC</ContactName>
                                                                    <TelephoneNumber>
                                                                   <NationalPhoneNumber>813-217-9512</NationalPhoneNumber>
                                                                    </TelephoneNumber>
                                                                    <ContactNumber>804-281-1402</ContactNumber>
                                                                    <EmailAddress>Jim.Paul@sscoop.com</EmailAddress>
                                                            </ContactInformation>

                                                    </PartnerInformation>
                                            </Buyer>
                                            <Seller>
                                                    <PartnerInformation>
                                                            <PartnerName>WalmartPartnerName</PartnerName>
                                                            <PartnerIdentifier Agency="IBM-EBID">0062668030000</PartnerIdentifier>
                                                    </PartnerInformation>
                                            </Seller>
                                            <ShipTo>
                                                    <PartnerInformation>
                                                            <PartnerName>ORANGE MADISON COOP ORANGE BR</PartnerName>
                                                            <PartnerIdentifier Agency="IBM-EBID">0238626420000</PartnerIdentifier>
                                                            <AddressInformation>
                                                                    <AddressLine>13323 JAMES MADISON HWY</AddressLine>
                                                                    <CityName>ORANGE</CityName>
                                                                    <StateOrProvince>VA</StateOrProvince>
                                                                    <PostalCode>22960</PostalCode>
                                                                    <PostalCountry>US</PostalCountry>
                                                            </AddressInformation>
                                                    </PartnerInformation>
                                            </ShipTo>
                                            <Payer>
                                                    <PartnerInformation>
                                                            <PartnerName>MOSLLC</PartnerName>
                                                            <PartnerIdentifier Agency="IBM-EBID">0089646370000</PartnerIdentifier>
                                                    </PartnerInformation>
                                            </Payer>
                                    </OrderCreatePartners>
                                    <OrderCreateDetails>
                                            <OrderCreateProductLineItem>
                                                    <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
                                                    <PurchaseOrderLineItemNumber>1</PurchaseOrderLineItemNumber>
                                                    <ProductIdentification>
                                                            <ProductIdentifier Agency="AssignedByManufacturer">883580921503</ProductIdentifier>
                                                            <ProductName>HARNESS XTRA 5.6L RUP BULK</ProductName>
                                                            <ProductDescription>HARNESS XTRA 5.6L RUP BULK</ProductDescription>
                                                    </ProductIdentification>
                                                    <ProductQuantity>
                                                            <Measurement>
                                                                    <MeasurementValue>1000</MeasurementValue>
                                                                    <UnitOfMeasureCode Domain="UN-Rec-20">GLL</UnitOfMeasureCode>
                                                            </Measurement>
                                                    </ProductQuantity>
                                                    <ScheduleDateTimeInformation ScheduleType="RequestedDelivery">
                                                            <DateTimeInformation>
                                                                    <DateTime xmlns="" DateTimeQualifier="On">20140822000000</DateTime>
                                                            </DateTimeInformation>
                                                    </ScheduleDateTimeInformation>
                                            </OrderCreateProductLineItem>
                                    </OrderCreateDetails>
                            </OrderCreateBody>
                    </OrderCreate>
            </soapenv:Body>
```

### This is the part which needs to be added

After element Buyer/ContactDescription I need add this

```
 <TelephoneNumber>
<NationalPhoneNumber>605225-1372</NationalPhoneNumber>
</TelephoneNumber>
```

This is the sample code I wrote. Can anyone please guide me?

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions" extension-element-prefixes="dp">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="attribute::Domain[starts-with(name(..),'PurchaseOrderType')]">
        <xsl:attribute name="Domain"><xsl:value-of select="translate(., '-', ' ')"/></xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="attribute::*">
        <xsl:copy/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="attribute::Domain[starts-with(name(..),'CurrencyCode')]">
        <xsl:attribute name="Domain"><xsl:value-of select="translate(., '-', ' ')"/></xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="attribute::*">
        <xsl:copy/>
    </xsl:template>
    <!--    <xsl:template match="attribute::Domain[starts-with(name(..),'LanguageCode')]">
<xsl:attribute name="Domain"><xsl:value-of select="translate('.', '-', ' ')"/>
</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
-->
    <xsl:template match="attribute::Domain[starts-with(name(..),'LanguageCode')]">
        <xsl:attribute name="Domain"><xsl:value-of select="concat('ISO ',substring-after(substring-before(.,'T'),'-'), '/T')"/></xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="attribute::*">
        <xsl:copy/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*[local-name()='DateTime']">
        <DateTime>
            <xsl:copy-of select="attribute::*"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="translate(., '-T:Z', '')"/>
        </DateTime>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*[local-name()='OrderCreate']">
        <OrderCreate Version="2.0.2">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </OrderCreate>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="attribute::*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <!--Adding the elements
        <TelephoneNumber>
        <NationalPhoneNumber>605225-1372</NationalPhoneNumber>
        </TelephoneNumber>-->
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="attribute::*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Buyer/ContactName">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <xsl:element name="TelephoneNumber">
             <xsl:attribute name="NationalPhoneNumber">605225-1372</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
        <!--<TelephoneNumber>
            <NationalPhoneNumber>605225-1372</NationalPhoneNumber>
        </TelephoneNumber>-->
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I'm not sure i got everything you meant, but I think you should look at your Xpath match "Buyer/ContactName" and try something like "Buyer//ContactName" or "ContactInformation/ContactName" as ContactName is not a direct child of Buyer as expected in this original Xpath.

Comment: Grandma, why are your indents so deep?

Comment: The input XML misses a closing bracket, after `</PartnerName` on line 67.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Thank you Lagivan and Mathias. Can you please explain the use of adding the namespace?
```

The answer is too long to be added in a comment, that is why I write a separate answer, even though @lagivan has already given an answer in terms of code.

The reason why adding the namespace solves your problem is that **elements with a namespace are different from ones without a namespace, even if their element names are the same**. Or put in another way,

```
<ns:number xmlns:ns="www.ns.com"/>
```

is *entirely different* from

```
<number>
```

`ns:number` is said to be *prefixed*, which is shorthand for saying it belongs to a certain namespace, in this case `www.ns.com`. Besides, there is a way to define a *default namespace*:

```
<number xmlns="www.ns.com">
  <digit/>
</number>
```

In the example above, there is a default namespace defined on the `number` element. This does not have any effect for the `number` element itself, but all descendants of `number` (in this case only `digit`) will take on this namespace.

---

Now, turning to your specific problem, the element you'd like to match (`ContactName`) is not itself prefixed, but it has a *default* namespace. This default namespace is not declared on the `ContactName` element, but higher up in the tree, on the `OrderCreate` element:

```
<OrderCreate Version="5.1.1" xmlns="urn:midx:names:specification:ces:schema:all:5:1:1">
```

Any descendant of `OrderCreate` will be in the namespace `urn:midx:names:specification:ces:schema:all:5:1:1`, for example ... `ContactName`.

What this means for your XSLT code is that if you want to match the `ContactName` element from the input, you must declare this namespace in your XSLT stylesheet and *prefix* the element name to be able to find it.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:my="urn:midx:names:specification:ces:schema:all:5:1:1">
```

Now you can write templates to match the descendant elements of `OrderCreate`, always prefixing them with `my:`:

```
<xsl:template match="my:ContactName">
```

On the other hand,

```
<xsl:template match="ContactName">
```

will never match anything because such an element (one that is called "ContactName" and one that is not in any namespace) does not exist in your input XML.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination Mathias :)

Answer (score 1):

To fix your issue you need two changes:

1. Specify the default namespace of your document in the root tag using some prefix, e.g. "my":

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:my="urn:midx:names:specification:ces:schema:all:5:1:1"
                xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions" extension-element-prefixes="dp">
```

2. Fix your Buyer template:

```xml
<xsl:template match="my:Buyer/my:PartnerInformation/my:ContactInformation/my:ContactName">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  <TelephoneNumber xmlns="urn:midx:names:specification:ces:schema:all:5:1:1">
    <NationalPhoneNumber>605225-1372</NationalPhoneNumber>
  </TelephoneNumber>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I guess this could be simplified to matching `<xsl:template match="my:ContactName>`, given the input XML.

Comment: No, there are many `ContactName` elements and only one under `Buyer` ancestor.

Comment: I see. You're absolutely right. But this will create a `TelephoneNumber` element in the output that does not have a namespace. You can fix it with `<TelephoneNumber xmlns="urn:midx:names:specification:ces:schema:all:5:1:1">`.

Comment: I'd expect the same as you logically but I've tested without explicit namespace declaration and I've found out it's not required. The new element inherits the default namespace from its ancestor.

Comment: See http://xsltransform.net/6qVRKvR - no, it does not inherit the namespace. With Saxon 6.5 at least.

Comment: You're right, thanks, I've updated the answer. I'm testing locally with Saxon-B 9.1, it's not the first time it appears to behave strangely.

Comment: If you are testing 1.0 stylesheets, always use Saxon 6.5. Use 9.* for XSLT 2.0 code. One last thing before I finally upvote your answer: The said template is _not_ selected because it was moved to the top, before the generic templates. It is selected because it is more specific than the generic ones. That's why it is assigned a higher priority, regardless of its position in the code.

Comment: Thank you Lagivan and Mathias. Can you please explain the use of adding the namespace?

Comment: @Kumar_y See my separate answer.